# Add domain to excel name

Tags: powershell

I'm currently connecting to a domain controller that is on a different domain. I'm trying to automate a report that tells us if a user is enabled and the last time they logged in. I'm looking to either add the domain name to the excel output or even rename the tabs inside the workbook. Currently I just name the excel sheet by the IP of the domain controller. I have a total of 8 domains Thank you for any help.

```
$domainserver = "ipaddress1" , "ipaddress2" , "ipaddress3"

foreach ($s in $domainserver){
  Get-ADUser -Credential $Credential -Server $s -Filter {Enabled -eq $TRUE} -Properties Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | 
    Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)}  | 
      Select Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | Sort-Object LastLogonDate |
        Export-Csv C:\temp\$s.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Using `Export-Excel` from DougFinkes `ImportExcel` module instead of `Export-Csv`  you could directly create an Excel file with multiple sheets named like your servers.

Comment: Do you have some way to correlate IP to domain? Maybe make a hashtable that translates IP to Domain? Or are you able to resolve those addresses via DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `Get-AdDomain` against the same server, to find domain details:

```
$domainserver = "ipaddress1" , "ipaddress2" , "ipaddress3"

foreach ($s in $domainserver)
{
  $domain = Get-AdDomain -Server $s -Credential $Credential

  Get-ADUser -Credential $Credential -Server $s -Filter {Enabled -eq $TRUE} -Properties Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | 
    Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)}  | 
      Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,@{Label='Domain'; Expression={$domain.DnsRoot}} | 
        Sort-Object LastLogonDate |
          Export-Csv C:\temp\$s.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```